# What's the purpose of shorting the base and collector of a transistor in current mirrors?

Tags: electric-circuits

I often see this diagram of a current mirror (as shown below).

As far as I know, the purpose of a current mirror is the ensure that the collector current for both transistors are equal.

This can simply be achieved by making sure that their base-emitter voltage is the same.  This can be done without shorting the base and collector of the left hand side transistor... Is shorting it redundant in any ways?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps better suited for EE SE, but... It is a really simple way to make sure that the base-emitter voltage is the same, don't you think?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror

Comment: @JonCuster Yup it's definitely simple way to make them the same, but why do I need that wire connecting (in fact, "short-circuiting") the left transistor's collector and base?

Comment: You do need a connection of *some* type to allow for base current.  Simply connecting the bases together is not enough; you must connect the bases to $V_{DD}$ through a resistor (or resistors) in order for there to be base current and thus, collector current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This can simply be achieved by making sure that their base-emitter
>   voltage is the same.

Not quite. The collector current can be written as

$$I_C = \beta_0\left(1 + \frac{V_{CB}}{V_A}\right)I_B$$

and so depends on the base current *and* the collector-base voltage (Early effect).  Connecting the collector and base together $(V_{CB}=0)$ removes this dependence on the collector-base voltage and the relationship simplifies to

$$I_C = \beta_0 I_B$$

Since $V_{BE1} = V_{BE2}$, the base currents are equal (assuming identical transistors etc.) and so we can then write

$$I_{REF} \equiv \frac{V_{DD} - V_{BE1}}{R_1} = I_{C1} + I_{B1} + I_{B2} = I_{B2}\left(2 + \beta_0\right)$$

and it follows that

$$I_{C2}=I_{REF}\frac{\beta_0}{2 + \beta_0}\left(1 + \frac{V_{CB2}}{V_A}\right) $$

If, on the other hand, $V_{CB1} \ne 0$ (for example, place a resistor between the collector and base of Q1 rather than a wire), the equation relating $I_{C2}$ to $I_{REF}$ is more complicated

$$I_{REF} \equiv \frac{V_{DD} - V_{BE1} - V_{CB1}}{R_1}$$

$$I_{C2}=I_{REF}\frac{\beta_0\left(1 + \frac{V_{CB2}}{V_A}\right)}{2 + \beta_0\left(1 + \frac{V_{CB1}}{V_A}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Shorting collector to base is NOT redundant, it serves the useful purpose of making conduction in the two transistors similar.  In particular,
the construction of a transistor includes a thin base region between emitter and collector, and that base region has an effective electrical
resistance.   Forcing all current in one transistor through
the base creates a voltage drop in the base spreading resistance
(often symbolized Rbb), while the (second) transistor takes
only a small fraction of its emitter current through that resistance.

Ebers-Moll ideal transistor:
$$I_c  =  \alpha I_{sat} \exp {q_e * V_{be} \over { k * T }}$$

and with base resistance
$$I_c =  \alpha I_{sat} \exp ({q_e * (V_{be} -I_b * R_{bb})\over { k * T }})$$

In the case of base-collector connection, Ib is a small fraction of the collector current.   If you don't connect the collector of the leftmost transistor, though, Ib is identical to the emitter current (which means it is larger than the collector current).   To match the two transistors' operation, you want the base-collector connected.

The open-collector use of B-E diode also changes the 'alpha' factor to exactly one, but that's less important.

Comment: This is an interesting interpretation of the OP's question; it had not occurred to me to consider the possibility that the OP was suggesting leaving the collector of Q1 open.

Comment: Leaving the collector of Q1 open would result in $I_{B2} = I_{REF}/2$ and thus $I_{C2} = \beta I_{REF}/2$ where $\beta = \beta_0\left(1 + V_{CB2}/V_A\right)$ which would be much more a current amplifier rather than a current mirror.

Comment: With collector open, the transistor Q1 has a base-emitter diode that makes the usual emitter current; it has negligible collector voltage, however, which means no current gain (beta is not a useful characterization of such a diode-connected transistor).   Base recombination (usually negligible) accounts for ALL the emitter current, very unlike a 'normal' transistor.